# Why won't the @username show in my comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

When I try and use the @username in my comments to answer to someone specifically, it disappears when my comment is posted. I've tried changing capitalization, spacing, everything. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is it the person who wrote the post you're commenting on? In that case, they get notified for *every* comment and the tag is redundant.